# Cannot create an object of type MediaPlayerClass

Tags: c#, media-player

```
MediaPlayer.MediaPlayerClass obj = new MediaPlayer.MediaPlayerClass();
```

When I create the object it shows the following error:

> Interop type MediaPlayer.MediaPlayerClass cannot be embedded, use
>   application interface instead.

Comment: Might need some more information like where does the `MediaPlayer` come from? Is it your own code or some library? If it is a somewhat common library, can you tag that in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can embed interop assemblies into your assembly so that you don't need to deploy them separately. If an interop assembly can't be embedded then open the Properties tab for that particular assembly in Visual Studio and set the setting "Embed Interop Types" to `False`.